# Unable to access Yahoo! mail without phone number

Tags: yahoo-mail

I have my Yahoo! account. I know my password and ID but when I try to access it, it requires my phone number. Unfortunately that phone number been lost. I haven’t linked it on my other Yahoo! mail account.

How can I get access to my account?

Answer (score 2):

This might be security purpose they are not allowing you to access your account. They wants verify your identity. Try to reset your password.
If you don't have option of mobile number and alternate email address, you can give answer to security question to reset password.

[Reset password](https://login.yahoo.com/account/challenge/username?authMechanism=secondary&yid=&done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com&s=eyJ2IjoyLCJjIjp0cnVlfQ--~lFDnytC2LiVWRP_TbR5e4ABibt7854W8gtpSfFmKXArkDV0UmQm51Ql5hgQk1WGuI_Wd44Hyq1A1F208zaMF8gWoD56eorL1NXGqQfTDoviwEZG9NsA4eLmFY.On2ajqRZMKCNAH5MJlxhbZXLFjp6IVoMUrj3iembjq14EpC.GHikdzHv7agyyqvOnC61wn5XFBA2nmrWR012NjSBWRGiN_4pxs6WTpi5nHVihcf8O3reKaj4zB_GGL4IQmx.DqR9Jp.R4EK_sK1hck6neA0kJfnDhZlzfXmyP7QAISCgC8wiFvb9vMTKjleQOJ8AlloLAXBAuKzCjCc0D_OyPwzxuHLV78xYtPjELYx3nDYOBXC6NEJOR6nVhgqXxx6QUSVUXp2QM3003vwOJbjAhm6njkM3t5C6CkWL0oXryEtfFC9A0LwQKtqHzD9NnabfXUrN9A66amO7JNRnhkyEw78g--&c=eyJ2IjoyLCJjIjp0cnVlfQ--~0BfefZi2LgWah8MhkTVZcedNZG9Kz.qXcRILd7o0PAD614uYqEZISUVjWPHENOqvVSKpXlNkQ7QTisiB3mS0R09JN5VzqMR.AM1nvFpLntf4feXALOWZfVFn24H_sgsdHsS41K6BYNNuKXAD97qtHTAL5GYckCGd.kUJarY3PI7JnI6TAFDSn0uuTM5zKOBqyPXmO4ydAQMaJ90djMnAqcPQrfWk6AfhHHvj3EA70ykKMVpOs_TI) <- use this link to direct reset your password.

If you still face problem, see the [help centre](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?locale=en_US&y=PROD_ACCT&page=contact&actp=lorax&token=Zh%2FBBVqXzLHlIbokbUqVWTUbuuQeXGkGnZzhKR2JQ4O6mMQdy9JSWfJCJWvc4C3%2F4ml2UKrHQ0nko7rLtSR522llJ3Ld%2FrEJKnIvphI9MT7K6teQxGvTCsV4OMT4g4cq9pf2peoAq96iUkXxenOQUJ%2FZpVq0%2FHxH#).

Click on above link. Go to **Password and sign in** -> **Problem with mobile code and notification** -> click on **Email**(envelope symbol), now write your problem to Yahoo customer care and wait for their response.